# Can't branch a single file with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, branch, dvcs

is this possible with Mercurial? and which Version Control system can do this besides Clearcase?

Comment: why do you think you need to branch a single file?

Comment: @jk， i miss the feature from clearcase, i am having trouble with maintaining different version for different customers.

Comment: I don't know if it'll work for you, but you might be able to use `mq` to do what you want.

Comment: MQ is mercurial queues. It's used to track small patches you want to apply.  It's one way to do this but probably overkill.

Comment: `mq`: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension . @Ry4an is right — it may be overkill — but it's worth mentioning. Basically, it lets you store changes as patch files. See my answer for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you could use MQ:

```
$ hg qnew -m "Changes for client0" client0
... change the file ...
$ hg qref # update the client0 patch with the changes
$ hg qpop # pop the changes off the queue stack
... develop like normal ...
... client0 asks for a build ...
$ hg qpu # apply client0's patch
$ make release
$ hg qpop
```

It would get a bit finicky if you've got to deal with a lot of clients… But it may be worth considering.

The other thing you could do, of course, is just commit a bunch of .diff files:

```
... make changes for client 0 ...
$ hg diff > client0.diff
$ hg revert --all
$ hg add client0.diff
$ hg ci -m "Adding client0 changes"
... develop ...
... client0 asks for a build ...
$ patch -p1 < client0.diff
$ make release
$ hg revert --all
```

Answer (score 4):

David is correct that you can't have a branch that exists on only a single file, but it's worth pointing out that people often have branches that alter only a single file.  Since the branch metadata is stored in the changeset, and since the changeset contains only a delta (change), having a branch that alters only a single files is nearly instantanous to create, update, commit, and merge, plus it takes up almost no space on disk.

Resultingly, it's a very common way to handle per-customer configurations.  Keep the tiny change for them in a branch, and merge from main, where development happened, into that branch, whenever you want to update their deployment.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. A branch in Mercurial is a snapshot of the entire repository state.

You could do it with CVS, though, as CVS tracks changes on a per-file basis :)